# Почему сосуществуют такие слова, как «небо» и «нёбо»?

Tags: фонетика, историческая-грамматика

Почему в русском языке есть и небо, и нёбо, и падеж, и падёж, и совершенный, и совершённый и т. д.? Понятно, что они различаются стилистически и по значению. Но как так вышло, что после перехода [э] в ['о] сохранились два варианта каждого из слов?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, чтобы указать на происхождение. С е - влияние церковнославянизмов, с ё - исконно русские слова. Если небо - праславянское от индоевропейской основы на -еs (небеса), то нёбо - новое русское, оно появилось только в 18 веке как переносное значение слова "небо" и получило русскую огласовку: е под ударением после мягкого перед твёрдым согл. перешёл в о (ё).

Падеж - старославянизм, падёж - русское, совершенный - старославянизм, совершённый - русское